# Laravel: can't access image from application

Tags: laravel-4

I uploaded images to a folder (pic) in my `Laravel public folder` and I save the full link in database.

I am now trying to access the images from a mobile application, I am getting 404 error instead.

Sample of the full link is below

```
http://domain.com/pic/iphone.png
```

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that your public part is missing. It should be something like:
`http://domain.com/public/pic/iphone.png`

And it's recommended to use [public_path()](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#paths) to retrieve the fully qualified path to the public directory. 
For example, use `public_path().'pic/pic-name.png'` to store the path to your pictures.

Comment: I tried  using `public`, it didn't work either. I should have mentioned that I am using a shared hosting, so I tried using `www` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this,

```
public_path('pic/pic-name.png');
```

Comment: I am accessing it from a mobile app

Comment: This is server side code. This has nothing to do with mobile app or web app.

Comment: So, I should save this along the `link` I save in the database?

Comment: No it's not required. You just have to save the file name in database and access it using the public path. Better you save the file path in config and use both the file path and file name to access your image in your app.

Comment: That will return `http://domain-name/home/domain-name/public_html/pic/pic-name.png` and I have tried this before without success too.

Comment: Try printing public_path() first. Let's see what it returns and if it's not returning "http://domain.com/", then there is a problem in your .htaccess or virtual host

Comment: it gave me `/home/domain-name/public_html/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64473/discussion-between-debasish-nayak-and-blackpearl).

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you copy the generated src url in your browser? Does it work? Is it possible that it is an upper/lowercase issue?

Comment: It gives me error when copied in a browser, and it is not a case issue.